# How does appfabric caching failover work?

Tags: caching, architecture, appfabric, high-availability

We are looking to use Windows AppFabric caching in a high availability scenario.

We would like to place the caching on the web servers, but the web servers do not have access to a database.

Therefore, the only option is the xml configuration file. This is on a share on the lead web server.

What happens if this server goes down? Is high availability only available when you have a clustered SQL Server or access to a SAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can designate multiple lead servers, however for HA SQL Server (clustered!) configuration is recommended by MS.

Comment: Thanks, but even with several lead servers, if the computer with the share that contains the config file goes down will the cluster go down?

Comment: You don't put the config file on a single machine, you put it on a NAS with redundancy and failover, or, better, a SAN with redundancy and failover. And I believe the only time a cluster node needs that file is on startup.

Comment: Thanks the config is read in 3 situations, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790929.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The XML configuration storage location can be a single point of failure, therefore MS recommend you use failover clustering which results in creating a folder with high availability.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790929.aspx) for more details.